# QvSAPConnector.dll error - Mismatch between SAP Transport and connector versions

Tags: qlikview, saprfc

I am using Qlikview version 11.20.12758.0 SR10 64-bit and SAP v6.0.

[image: SAP version]
[image: QvSAPconnector version]

After installing QV SAP connector v6.0, i am trying to connect to SAP by passing relevant details - IP, Client Id, System number, User, Pass. Facing below error message:
Mismatch between SAP Transport and connector versions. Please import the correct SAP transport. Unable to retrieve transport version from system. Invalid parameter 'RFC_FUNCTION_HANDLE' was passed to the API call

[image: QV SAP connector error]

Referred following links, however, issue persists:

```
https://community.qlik.com/thread/99142

https://community.qlikview.com/thread/139623

https://qlikcommunity.qliktech.com/thread/142955
```

Consulted SAP guy to know if there is issue with Access rights, however, access is also available on the User.

I learnt that after QvSAPconnector, it should show Transports folder under path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\QlikTech\Custom Data\QvSAPConnector\

However, Transports folder is missing.

[image: Transports folder missing]

Please guide me to resolve this error. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be a case for the QlikView support.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use the SAP Connectors (whether you are connecting to ERP or SAP BW), you will need to import transports provided by Qlik into your system(s) as these are needed for Qlik's connectors to function. These transports contain various "helper" programs (such as the version check as shown in your error message screenshot) as well as authorisation objects that are needed.

Depending on the connector that you are using, in the case of the "SAP" connector, you will need to import the relevant transports, and this also depends on the version of the system that you are going to be importing the transports into.

More information on which transports you should use are given here:

http://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/SAP_Connectors_Help/Content/6.4/Installation/Installing-the-transports.htm

As mentioned in the above link:

> Data extraction and user profile transports are installed in the SAP
>   system. These are available in the following folder on the computer,
>   copied there during the installation of the Qlik SAP Connector:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\QlikTech\Custom Data\QvSAPConnector\Transports
> ```

I noticed that you uploaded an image of a different folder which just contains the SAP Connector logs. The transports are always installed in the above location.

Once the transports are imported, you should then be able to use the connectors to connect and extract data.